# CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window could not be created from binder

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm getting this CursorWindowAllocationException when run my code:

code:

```
     try{
        Uri uri;
        uri = RawContactsEntity.CONTENT_URI;

        final String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?";
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { contactId.id };
        cur = _resolver.query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cur == null)
            return null;
        if (cur.moveToFirst() == false)
        {
            cur.close();
            return null;
        }
        entityIterator = RawContacts.newEntityIterator(cur);

        if (entityIterator == null)
        {
            Logger.error(TAG, "EntityIterator is null");
            return null;
        }

        while (entityIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Entity entity = entityIterator.next();
            for (NamedContentValues namedContentValues : entity
                    .getSubValues())
            {
                ContentValues contentValues = namedContentValues.values;
                String key = contentValues.getAsString(Data.MIMETYPE);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    contentValuesList.add(contentValues);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cur != null)
        {
            cur.close();
        }
        if (entityIterator != null)
        {
            entityIterator.close();
        }
    }
```

but sometimes I get this exception:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window could not be created from binder.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:141)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:41)
    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:697)
    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:695)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.newFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:706)
    at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.getWindow(BulkCursorNative.java:196)
    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.onMove(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:94)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:178)
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:201)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToFirst(CursorWrapper.java:65)
    at android.content.CursorEntityIterator.<init>(CursorEntityIterator.java:39)
    at android.provider.ContactsContract$RawContacts$EntityIteratorImpl.<init>(ContactsContract.java:2844)
    at android.provider.ContactsContract$RawContacts.newEntityIterator(ContactsContract.java:2818)
    at com.wangma.wubi.datasource.device.contact.ContactDeviceDataSource.loadOneContact(ContactDeviceDataSource.java:156)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.ContactList$1.getNext(ContactList.java:73)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.UriWordListBase$PlatformFullIterator.hasNext(UriWordListBase.java:60)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase.findChangeList(WordListBase.java:530)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase.platformFullUpdate(WordListBase.java:454)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase.goPlatformFullUpdate(WordListBase.java:437)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase.access$1200(WordListBase.java:38)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase$1.update(WordListBase.java:422)
    at com.wangma.wubi.services.upload.grammar.content.WordListBase$PendingFullUpdate$1.run(WordListBase.java:174)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at com.nuance.balerion.services.jobs.LooperJob$LooperStarter.run(LooperJob.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This crash is not easy to reproduce though, but it does happen occassionally. Does anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316082/cursor-window-could-not-be-created-from-binder