# Android cursor window could not be created from binder

Tags: android, cursor

I have checked [Cursor window could not be created from binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316082/cursor-window-could-not-be-created-from-binder).

I am getting issue of memory while fetching contacts from phone-book,
below is my code and I am testing it in OS 4+

```
Cursor cursor =managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{Data._ID,"display_name","photo_id","starred"},
    null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC , "
    + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER+ " DESC" );
Cursor pCur;
Cursor emailCur;
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    pCur = WP7Main.this.managedQuery(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projPhone, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
        + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
}
```

And I am doing this in asyncTask, its almost 700+ contacts

I am getting below error

```
E/CursorWindow(25078): Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.
W/dalvikvm(25078): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c66930)
E/AndroidRuntime(25078): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
E/AndroidRuntime(25078): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(25078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)*
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have You tried to close pCur? Seems it should be closed at the end of every iteration.

Comment: @ sandrstar: I have all tried which shown on linkes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316082/cursor-window-could-not-be-created-from-binder

Answer (score 0):

managedQuery is deprecated since API 11, you should use CursorLoader. I'm guessing the exception you are seeing is because you are trying to run the managedQuery method (which is on the Activity thread) from your async background thread. I agree that with such a large request you want to do it on its own thread, you just need to use a different method.